# Parse pdf with Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to parse pdf with the code below, I added the code that parse file in **plugins/index.js** and **test.spec.js**, but when I try to handle the promise with `.then()` instead of parsed text I get `[object Promise]` in console. How to handle the promise and get plain text?

**index.js**

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const pdf = require('pdf-parse');

const repoRoot = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..')

const parsePdf = async (pdfName) => {
  const pdfPathname = path.join(repoRoot, pdfName)
  let dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync(pdfPathname);
  return await pdf(dataBuffer) 
}

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    getPdfContent(pdfName) {
      return String(parsePdf(pdfName))
    }
  })
}
```

**test.spec.js**

```
it('Parse PDF', ()=>{
        cy.task('getPdfContent', 'test.pdf').then((content) => 
            console.log(content)
          )
    })
```

Comment: If you want to test if pdf contains some text you can do this

`cy.readFile("./downloads/sample.pdf").should('contain', 'This is a small demonstration')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just return the promise from the task, see [Waiting for Promises](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise#Waiting-for-Promises)

> return a promise to cy.then()
> that is awaited until it resolves

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    getPdfContent(pdfName) {
      return parsePdf(pdfName)   
    }
  })
}
```

```js
it('Parse PDF', ()=>{
  cy.task('getPdfContent', 'test.pdf').then((content) => 
    console.log(content)
    /*
     {
       numpages: 1, 
       numrender: 1, 
       info: {
         CreationDate: "…"
         Creator: "…"
         IsAcroFormPresent: false
         IsXFAPresent: false
         ModDate: "…"
         ...
       }, 
       metadata: null, 
       text: "…"
       version: "…"
   */
  )
})
```